# Workaround for CarrierWave multiple file upload using sqlite3 in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

In my team development environment, we are using sqlite3 which comes default in Rails.

However, carrierwave's implementation of multi files upload require database that supports array/json datatype.

Are there any workaround so that it will work on our development environment without installing other database such as postgres?

I'm following the instructions over here https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible workaround would be to create a separate model for the uploads:

```
class ImagesContainer
  has_many :uploads
end

class Upload
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  belongs_to ImagesContainer
end
```