# carrierwave multiple image upload with one button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, image-uploading

My question starts from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471165/how-to-save-dynamic-number-of-images-using-carrierwave/34471422?noredirect=1#comment56687096_34471422).
I'm using Sqlite3 and my model relation looks like this.

```
class ImagePost < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attachments
end
```

My attachment

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :image_post
    mount_uploader :img, S3uploaderUploader
end
```

The thing is I want to make my users uploading their images with one button. Right now, I did

```
<%= form_tag img_upload_create_path, method: "POST", html: { multipart: true } do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag("image_post_id", @image_post.id ) %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag("user_id", current_user.id ) %>

        <%= file_field_tag 'user_pic', multiple: true, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg' %>

        <%= submit_tag "image-upload", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
      <% end %>
```

My image_upload controller,

```
class ImgUploadController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user_img = Attachment.create(
        hasuk_house_id: params[:image_post_id],
        user_id: current_user.id,
        img: params[:user_pic]
        )
  end
end
```

But when I submit files, `@user_img.img = nil` What am I going to do?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads)

Comment: Yes I did. But I also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951168/workaround-for-carrierwave-multiple-file-upload-using-sqlite3-in-development). It doesn't make any problems?

Comment: That's right, you won't be able to use `json` or `array` column type with sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a closer look, you have multiple problems going on here, first:

```
<%= form_tag img_upload_create_path, method: "POST", html: { multipart: true }
```

should be:

```
<%= form_tag(img_upload_create_path, { multipart: true, method: "POST"})
```

( `form_tag` arguments are structured a bit different from `form_for`)

and then you need to instruct rails to put your files in `params` as an array, you do that by using a name convention for form elements. so instead of:

```
 <%= file_field_tag 'user_pic', multiple: true, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg' %>
```

you need:

```
<%= file_field_tag 'user_pic[]', multiple: true, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg' %>
```

and finally in your controller, you'll have the files in `params[:user_pic]` which is an array, so you'll have to loop through it and create your attachments for each one:

```
params[:user_pic].each do |pic|
  Attachment.create(
        hasuk_house_id: params[:image_post_id],
        user_id: current_user.id,
        img: pic
  )
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah! your solution is perfectly working. I was trying to make my `img`to json and looking for solutions. Anyway, your solution is really good! Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.